# Why doesn't TABLE obey my RIGHT css style?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have the following code and was expecting TABLE will shrink with browser window. But it doesn't. Why?

```
<body>
    <table style="position:fixed; left:50px; right:50px; bottom:50px; border:solid">
        <tr>
            <td style="border:solid">Left cell</td>
            <td style="border:solid">Right cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

***UPDATE***

I was even going to be disappointed with CSS language at all, but apparently people who were saying it is impossible to apply both RIGHT and LEFT styles were WRONG!

So it IS possible, for DIVs for example.

Also I found that the following code works better:

```
<table>
    <tr style="position:fixed; left:50px; right:50px; bottom:50px; border:solid">
        <td style="border:solid; width:inherit">Left cell</td>
        <td style="border:solid; width:inherit">Right cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely **can** apply both `right` and `left` properties to an element. The problem (I think) is that tables are a special case - they will only stretch to fit the width of the content in them if a width is not explicitly specified.

You need to do [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/EaX3A/), using a positioned wrapper `div` and setting both the `width` and `height` of the `table` to fill that.

Comment: Wow! I was experimenting with DIV and really saw it obeys better!

Comment: May be there is a way to remove strange TABLE behavior?

Comment: I don't think so - your best bet is to accept the wrapper div, or recreate your table with a div if possible.

Comment: I found that behavior is better if style is applied to TR tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `left` or `right` but not both!!!!
Try this:

```
<body style="padding: 50px;margin:0;">
    <table style="border-style:solid;width:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="border-style:solid">Left cell</td>
            <td style="border-style:solid">Right cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/R8aS8/

Comment: Wow! This is for TABLE only or for DIV too? So how to make table to have fixed distance from browser window?

Comment: I can't touch BODY, I should only place TABLE how I need. Is it possible with CSS?

Comment: I can't do this too. I am trying to apply style for elements which generated by third party software (GWT). So, it is impossiple to position elements with CSS? Very epic fail I guess: the language can't do which it was intended to...

Comment: I think that: http://jsfiddle.net/R8aS8/2/ is the best thing what you could do only with css

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is to put the table in a container with `padding-left: 50px` and `padding-right:50px` and give the table 100% width. You should also consider putting your css in a separate file as inline css gets messy.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      div.wrapper { padding: 0px 50px; }
      table.fullwidth { width: 100%; border: 1px solid #333; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <table class="fullwidth">
        <tr>
          <td >Left cell</td>
          <td>Right cell</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This didn't work. The size of table became 100% of browser window and it wasn't fit it at all.

Comment: I assumed that was what you wanted as you were setting both left and right to `50px`.

Comment: I was wishing that the distance between right side of the browser window and right side of the table was 50px. Ans also for the left sides of both.

Comment: So you *do* want the table to fill the width of the browser (apart from the 50px on either side)? Did you put it in another container? I've updated my answer with an example of what I mean, which does exactly what you describe as I understand it.

Comment: I can't control all the page in my main task. I can just plug something with position:fixed -- this is a requirement.